What do the stars mean after finishing a race in Mario Kart 8?
Having finished a race in a tournament of Mario Kart 8, I can push X and mark (?) that race with a start.
What is the reason for this? What can I achieve after having awarded six stars on six races?


If you press X after a race you can save a replay of it (the same replay you could view by pressing "Highlights ansehen" in the screenshot).
If you return to the main menu and go to "Mario Kart TV" you can view the saved replays.

The amount of stars represents the amount of saved replays with a maximum of 6 at any time. You can delete replays in the Mario Kart TV menu.
